# XSL stylesheet for a Filemaker pro XML export

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

I am creating a stylesheet for a filemaker pro XML export however the output does not render when I load it in a browser. I have tested the XSL code with other sample XML data and it renders fine in a browser however it will not work with the filemaker pro format. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><!-- This grammar has been deprecated - use FMPXMLRESULT instead -->
<?xml-stylesheet version="1.0" href="style.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<FMPDSORESULT>
    <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
    <DATABASE>Database.fmp12</DATABASE>
    <LAYOUT>Manage Parts</LAYOUT>
    <ROW MODID="177" RECORDID="2104">
        <Code>T034-00596</Code>
        <Description>INFO GUIDE</Description>
        <Size>2</Size>
        <Units>/1</Units>
        <Price>5</Price>        
    </ROW>
    <ROW MODID="178" RECORDID="2105">
        <Code>T034-00597</Code>
        <Description>INFO GUIDE</Description>
        <Size>2</Size>
        <Units>/3</Units>
        <Price>4</Price>        
    </ROW>
    <ROW MODID="177" RECORDID="2104">
        <Code>T034-00598</Code>
        <Description>INFO GUIDE</Description>
        <Size>2</Size>
        <Units>/2</Units>
        <Price>6</Price>        
    </ROW>  
</FMPDSORESULT>
```

This is my XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/FMPDSORESULT">

<html>
    <Head>
    … header omitted for brevity …
    </Head>
        <body>          
            <xsl:for-each select="ROW">
                <h1><xsl:value-of select="Code" /></h1>
            </xsl:for-each>     
        </body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please never describe a problem as "it will not work". Always post the expected result, and explain how your own result differs from it.  Also make sure to post enough code for us to reproduce the problem. The code you have posted "works" just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is **not** what a FileMaker export looks like. FileMaker places the exported nodes in its own *namespace*:

```
<FMPDSORESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
```

Your stylesheet must declare this namespace, assign it a prefix and use this prefix to address elements in the XML source:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fmp="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult"
exclude-result-prefixes="fmp">

<xsl:template match="/fmp:FMPDSORESULT">
    <html>
        <head>
        … header omitted for brevity …
        </head>
        <body>          
            <xsl:for-each select="fmp:ROW">
                <h1><xsl:value-of select="fmp:Code" /></h1>
            </xsl:for-each>     
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```